# Dependent replacement in Lean

Tags: lean4

I'm stuck on proving extensionality results for my dependent structures in Lean 4. It's turning out to be very difficult to show equalities for these dependent structures, since I require a kind of substitution for dependent types. I kind of want to avoid `HEq` so I can to avoid complaints about equality of types.

Here's an example for the "category" structure, but it's just an example I'm trying to make work (I really want extensionality results for many of my dependent structures)

Here's the structure:

```
import Init.Core

-- A category C consists of:
structure category.{u₀,v₀} where
  Obj : Type u₀
  Hom : Obj → Obj → Type v₀
  Idn : (X:Obj) → Hom X X
  Cmp : (X:Obj) → (Y:Obj) → (Z:Obj) → (_:Hom X Y) → (_:Hom Y Z) → Hom X Z
  Id₁ : (X:Obj) → (Y:Obj) → (f:Hom X Y) → 
    Cmp X Y Y f (Idn Y) = f
  Id₂ : (X:Obj) → (Y:Obj) → (f:Hom X Y) → 
    Cmp X X Y (Idn X) f = f
  Ass : (W:Obj) → (X:Obj) → (Y:Obj) → (Z:Obj) → (f:Hom W X) → (g:Hom X Y) → (h:Hom Y Z) →
    (Cmp W X Z) f (Cmp X Y Z g h) = Cmp W Y Z (Cmp W X Y f g) h


-- Notation for the identity map which infers the category:
def identity_map (C : category) (X : C.Obj) := C.Idn X
notation "_(" C ")" => identity_map C

-- Notation for composition which infers the category and objects:
def composition (C : category) {X : C.Obj} {Y : C.Obj} {Z : C.Obj} (f : C.Hom X Y) (g : C.Hom Y Z) : C.Hom X Z := C.Cmp X Y Z f g
notation g "∘_(" C ")" f => composition C f g

macro "CAT" : tactic => `(tactic| repeat (rw [category.Id₁]) ; repeat (rw [category.Id₂]) ; repeat (rw [category.Ass]))
```

I first defined two helping functions for the extensionality result to be expressed:

```
-- rewriting via obj
def  (C : category) (D : category) (obj : C.Obj = D.Obj) (X : C.Obj) : D.Obj := by
rw [obj]
exact X

-- rewriting via hom
def ℍ (C : category) (D : category) (obj : C.Obj = D.Obj) (X : C.Obj) (Y : C.Obj) (hom : D.Hom ( C D obj X) ( C D obj Y)) = C.Hom X Y ) (f : C.Hom X Y) : D.Hom ( C D obj X) ( C D obj Y) := by
rw [hom]
exact f
```

These help to avoid `HEq` which I don't want to use.

Now, category.mk is a bit complex and of course dependent:

```
#check category.mk
```

I'm trying to work with this structure "equal_categories", which pertains to sufficient conditions for categories to be equal:

```
structure equal_categories where
  Fst : category
  Snd : category
  Obj : Snd.Obj = Fst.Obj
  Hom : (X : Fst.Obj) →
      (Y : Fst.Obj) →
      Snd.Hom
      ( Fst Snd Obj X)
      ( Fst Snd Obj Y)
      =
      Fst.Hom X Y
--  Idn : (X : Fst.Obj) → 
  Cmp : (X Y Z : Fst.Obj) →
      (f : Fst.Hom X Y) →
      (g : Fst.Hom Y Z) →
      (ℍ Fst Snd Obj X Z
      (Hom X Z)
      (Fst.Cmp X Y Z f g))
      =
      Snd.Cmp
      ( Fst Snd Obj X)
      ( Fst Snd Obj Y)
      ( Fst Snd Obj Z)
      (ℍ Fst Snd Obj X Y (Hom X Y) f)
      (ℍ Fst Snd Obj Y Z (Hom Y Z) g)
```

Now I want to show this

```
theorem CatExt (P : equal_categories) : P.Fst = P.Snd := by
sorry
```

I've found that I can witness a constituent of the `equal_categories` with what I know, but it's really very difficult to perform the necessary replacements to get `CatExt`. Does anyone have any advice?

Note this is Lean 4.

Edit: after further thought, I am comfortable using HEq because I figured out how to obtain an equality from two HEq-equal terms of the same type.

I kind of want to show this:

```
def this (X : Type) (Y : Type) (p : X = Y) : HEq (category.mk X) (category.mk Y) := by 
sorry
```

```
theorem CatExtObj  {a b:Type} (H : Eq a b) : HEq (category.mk a) (category.mk b) :=
Eq.recOn H (HEq.refl (category.mk a))


theorem hcongrsdfjkjkjkjk {X Y:Type} (H : Eq X Y) : HEq (category.mk X) (category.mk Y) :=
Eq.recOn H (HEq.refl (category.mk X))
```

Edit: here's a result I want on functors:

````
-- definition of a functor
structure functor (C : category) (D : category) where
   Obj : ∀(_ : C.Obj),D.Obj
   Hom : ∀(X : C.Obj),∀(Y : C.Obj),∀(_ : C.Hom X Y),D.Hom (Obj X) (Obj Y)
   Idn : ∀(X : C.Obj),Hom X X (C.Idn X) = D.Idn (Obj X)
   Cmp : ∀(X : C.Obj),∀(Y : C.Obj),∀(Z : C.Obj),∀(f : C.Hom X Y),∀(g : C.Hom Y Z),
   D.Cmp (Obj X) (Obj Y) (Obj Z) (Hom X Y f) (Hom Y Z g) = Hom X Z (C.Cmp X Y Z f g)

structure equal_functors (C : category) (D : category) where
  Fst : functor C D
  Snd : functor C D
  Obj : Fst.Obj = Snd.Obj
  Hom : (X : C.Obj) → (Y : C.Obj) → (f : C.Hom X Y) → (HEq (Fst.Hom X Y f) (Snd.Hom X Y f))

theorem FunExtOne (C : category) (D : category) (P : equal_functors C D) (H : Eq P.Fst.Obj P.Snd.Obj) : HEq (functor.mk P.Fst.Obj) (functor.mk P.Snd.Obj) := 
Eq.recOn H (HEq.refl (functor.mk P.Fst.Obj))

theorem FunExt (C : category) (D : category) (P :equal_functors C D) : P.Fst = P.Snd := by 
sorry
```
````

Comment: Your MWE doesn't type check.  I think you need to replace `Cat.Obj` with `category`?

Comment: Sorry, I made some fixes

Comment: I've got to fix it but don't have time right now

Comment: Also your def of blackboard Hom should use `exact f` in place of sorry, no?

Comment: Oh, you fixed it! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Having thought about this for a bit, I'm not 100% certain what you are trying to prove is provable in Lean.  (But I'm not positive it isn't provable either.)

Here is what I do know:

Your  and `ℍ` definitions could be replaced with the built in [`cast`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Init/Prelude.html#cast).  Indeed [`HEq`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Init/Prelude.html#HEq) is really just reasoning about cast:

> Heterogeneous equality. `HEq a b` asserts that `a` and `b` have the same type, and casting `a` across the equality yields `b`, and vice versa.

And one natural way to prove facts about heterogeneous equality is just to convert it to cast equalities (with [`cast_heq`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Init/Core.html#cast_heq)) and reason about the equalities.

Now what you are trying to prove seems to boil down to proving a version of function extentionality for heterogeneous equality, namely

```
theorem heq_funext (α β : Type u) (γ : Type v) (p : α = β)
    (f : α -> γ) (g : β -> γ)
    (h : (a : α) -> f a = g (cast p a))
  : HEq f g
```

Edit: The reason it comes down to this is that for two dependent structures (say `Sigma`) to be equal it is necessary and sufficient for the non-dependent fields to be equal and the dependent fields to be HEq.  See for example, [`Sigma.ext_iff`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Mathlib/Data/Sigma/Basic.html#Sigma.ext_iff).

But I don't know if this is provable.  Indeed `HEq` comes with a big warning:

> You should avoid using this type if you can. Heterogeneous equality does not have all the same properties as Eq, because the assumption that the types of `a` and `b` are equal is often too weak to prove theorems of interest. One important non-theorem is the analogue of `congr`: If `HEq f g` and `HEq x y` and `f x` and `g y` are well typed it does not follow that `HEq (f x) (g y)`.

Indeed that was the very thing I was stuck on when trying to prove `heq_funext`.

---

Here is my partial proof of `heq_funext`:

```
theorem heq_fun_ext (α β : Type u) (γ : Type v) (p : α = β)
    (f : α -> γ) (g : β -> γ)
    (h : (a : α) -> f a = g (cast p a))
  : HEq f g := by
  have pp : (α -> γ) = (β -> γ) := by
    simp [p]
  have hh : f = (cast pp.symm g) := by
    apply funext
    intro a
    rw [h, <-heq_eq_eq]
    sorry
  simp [hh, cast_heq]
```

The goal for `sorry` is:

```
    α β : Type u
    γ : Type v
    p : α = β
    f : α → γ
    g : β → γ
    h : ∀ (a : α), f a = g (cast p a)
    pp : (α → γ) = (β → γ)
    a : α
    ⊢ HEq (g (cast p a)) (cast (_ : (β → γ) = (α → γ)) g a)
```

This is basically a form of the congruence lemma the warning said was not provable.

---

I'm not certain my skepticism is correct, but I would also think this lemma would be in Mathlib if provable.  I think there is a better chance this sort of thing works in homotopy or cubical type theory, but I'm not certain of that either.

Comment: I don't think your proposition is an example of a problem. I suspect the issue is that if you start with just `HEq f g`, then you know `(α → γ) = (β → δ)`, but that does not tell you `α = β` and `γ = δ`. That would be assuming that `→` is injective. But you have explicitly assumed `α = β` instead, so that issue doesn't arise.

Comment: @DanDoel do you think my heq_funext lemma is provable, or do you have another way to prove the OPs theorem?  (Although I’m pretty sure if you can prove the OP’s theorem you can prove my lemma with the same method.)

Comment: To be clear, by “the OP’s theorem” I mean CatExt.

Comment: The most important extensionality result for me is one on functors, which may be easier.

Comment: @Cayley-Hamilton Can you be more specific?  What is this functor result you want proved?  Also, the main takeaway I think is that equality of dependent structures (especially ones which contain types) is hard in Lean.   Many reasonable sounding results are just not provable.  That I think is why the existing category theory library works with isomorphisms more than equalities.

Comment: @JasonRute I mean your lemma is provable. I don't know about the OP's stuff. [Here](https://hub.darcs.net/dolio/agda-share/browse/HEqExt.agda) is your lemma in Agda in a few ways, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @DanDoel is correct.  I should be able to prove my lemma and therefore the OP's lemma CatExt (at least if using `cast` in place of the add hoc definitions).  I'll update my answer later.  Sorry about this.

Comment: No way Jason you're the best

Comment: I made some edits to the question to add in extensionality for functors.