# increasing the universe level of a type in Lean by force

Tags: lean, universe

Given some term

```
A : Sort u
```

in Lean, is there a way to artificially increase the universe level and promote A to a term

```
A : Sort (u + 1)
```

in a higher universe?

Context: I have written down the definition of a large category in Lean.

```
structure Cat : Type 2 :=
(ob : Type 1)
(mor : Π p : ob × ob, Type 1)
(id : Π x : ob, mor(x,x))
(comp {x y z : ob} : Π g : mor(y,z), Π f : mor(x,y), mor(x,z))
(assoc {x y z w : ob} : ∀f : mor(x,y), ∀g : mor(y,z), ∀h : mor(z,w),
  comp h (comp g f) = comp (comp h g) f)
(leftn {x y : ob} : ∀f : mor(x,y), comp (id y) f = f)
(rightn {x y : ob} : ∀f : mor(x,y), comp f (id x) = f)
```

Next I want to define a category SET of sets and a category PROP of propositions. The morphism types in the category of sets should be the standard function types, and the morphism types in the category of propositions should be implications.

```
Type : Type 1
```

is of the right universe level, but I have problems with the morphism types in SET and with both function and morphism types for PROP.

```
Prop : Type 0
φ : Prop, ψ : Prop ⊢ φ → ψ : Sort 0
```

The universe level is too low for my definition of a category. Is there a way to fix this without introducing different versions of Cat for different universe level combinations?

Comment: `ULift` can raise universe levels, but I'd say this is usually not the best approach

Comment: Why not use universe variables instead of hard coding the level?

Comment: Here is the definition of [semigroup](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/algebra/group/defs.html#semigroup) in Mathlib.  It uses universe levels for the carrier to specifically avoid your sort of problem.  (It also uses a semi [bundled](https://leanprover-community.github.io/glossary.html#bundled-vs-unbundled) approach where the carrier isn’t in the data of the structure.)  This is pretty consistent throughout mathlib.

Comment: @JasonRute Thx! The thing is that even when I use universe levels, I will still have the problem that for SET the universe level of the morphism types will be 1 below that of the object type, while for other categories this isn't the case. But I guess I can just use two universes, right?

Comment: @Nico I might be misunderstanding, but you may want to try `Sort u` instead of `Type u`.  Also I’d look at the existing category theory library starting with the definition of [category](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/category_theory/category/basic.html#category_theory.category) to see how it compares to yours.

Comment: Oh I see.  Yes two universes works.  See the definition of category in this PA question: https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/2352/dependent-replacement-in-lean

Answer (score 2):

You can define a universe polymorphic version of `Cat`.

```
universes u v

structure Cat : Type (max u v + 1) :=
(ob : Type u)
(mor : Π p : ob × ob, Type v)
(id : Π x : ob, mor(x,x))
(comp {x y z : ob} : Π g : mor(y,z), Π f : mor(x,y), mor(x,z))
(assoc {x y z w : ob} : ∀f : mor(x,y), ∀g : mor(y,z), ∀h : mor(z,w),
  comp h (comp g f) = comp (comp h g) f)
(leftn {x y : ob} : ∀f : mor(x,y), comp (id y) f = f)
(rightn {x y : ob} : ∀f : mor(x,y), comp f (id x) = f)
```

If you ever need to specify universes explicitly you can write `Cat.{u, v}` for the Type of Categories with objects in `u` and morphisms in `v`. You could also define universe polymorphic versions of most of the well known categories, for example the category of Types could start something like this

```
def Types : Cat :=
{ ob := Type u,
  mor := fun X, X.1 -> X.2,
```